# Reading binary plists with Flash

Tags: xml, flash, ios, plist, binary-data

We're writing an iPad app that saves out information as a plist for later reading by a Flash movie.  Originally we designed the plist to export out as a simple plain text xml file and the Flash player read that fine.  The problem with that was that the files were monumentally big and verbose so we converted it over to a binary plist.  Unfortunately after making the changes necessary for a binary xml file to be read on the Flash end and the iOS device end, we're having no luck with this new file going through.

Has anyone developed something using binary Plists to talk between an iOS/Mac device and Flash?  Are there encoding issues or something else we should be thinking about?  I'm even cool with doing a work around on the server end to transform a binary plist to a binary xml file that Flash can read if that is a solution.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps http://code.google.com/p/as3plist/wiki/Intro is what you're looking for? I haven't tried it, but it came up in the same search as your question.

Edit: I misparsed your question, sounds like you actually have something like this, but it's not working. Still, maybe this will give you a clue as to why your own version's not working.